# Create a loop inside php to work in a query

Tags: php, mysql

i'm building this little function,

what i need is this query to print me values. Which means, i have this array named $checked1 which i need to print each of it inside a query.

My code up to now is:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT $checked FROM hostess");


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {foreach( $checked1 as $key => $value){

      echo "<td>" . $row['$value'] . "</td>";


}
```

But it's not working.

Can you tell me what's wrong?

Thanks..

Comment: What are the value of `$checked` and `$checked1`?  And what do you mean by "not working"?  What's happening when you try to run the code?

Comment: There is this hostess table which has fields like id,name etc etc..

Comment: Aleks, so the $checked is just an implode of the $checked1 array...., it doesn't print anything..

Comment: Or the error you're getting...?  'It be broke' isn't much to go on.

Comment: Please don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/q0gwD) (see the [red box](http://goo.gl/OWwr2)). Instead, you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/orrj0) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/YXyWL) will help you. If you care to learn, [this is a good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/a4i0f).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
echo "<td>" . $row['$value'] . "</td>";
```

should be

```
echo "<td>" . $row[$value] . "</td>";
```

Comment: Hey, i can't believe i didn't see this option, i've been struggling for this, many many thanks...